# How to Write a function that takes a word and returns the first and last letter with a * in the middle. [PYTHON]

Tags: python-3.x

What have if done wrong or right so far  I have no idea what im doing 
this is for my study for my cert 3

```
 def func(hell):
     value=hell[::3]
     return value

print(func("hell"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access the first letter with `word[0]`, and the last with `word[-1]`. Then use string concatenation to add a `"*"`:

```
def func(word):
    if word:
        return word[0]+"*"+word[-1]
```

---

```
>>> func("hello")
'h*o'
>>> func("foo")
'f*o'
>>> func("")
>>>
```

Comment: Also is this for Python 3.x?

Comment: Try it... but it works for any python from 1.0 to 3.5.